# template to add a h2 tag around a field group title

Tags: theming

I have a field group in my content type. I want to wrap an h2 tag around the title of the field group. I have tried looking at the node.tpl.php and field.tpl.php for a way to wrap just the title, and have not succeeded.

Where can I target this?

Comment: Field groups are just used to group content when editing nodes. I've never seen a field group title being output when viewing a node. What page do you want this h2 tag to appear on?

Answer (score 0):

The way I dealt with this was to change the wrapper in the Manage Display section from a fieldset to a div. Then, options for the label element could be changed from inside the UI.